# java 8 - immutablemap for loop

Tags: java, java-8, guava

Im new to java, I used a hashmap initially and did a forEach over that, it worked fine:

```
Map<String, Integer> testmap = new HashMap<>();
IntStream.range(0, 100).forEach(n -> {
                testmap.put("teststring-" + Integer.toString(n), 1);
            });
String x = testmap.entrySet().stream().filter(..);
```

However, now I have a ImmutableHashMap which I want to do the same above steps, how would I do that? I tried doing

```
ImmutableMap.Builder<String, Integer> testmap = ImmutableMap.builder(); 
IntStream.range(0, 100).forEach(n -> {
            testmap.put("teststring-" + Integer.toString(n), 1);
        });
testmap.build();
String x = testmap.entrySet().stream().filter(...); // throws an error while compile

cannot find symbol
    [javac]         String testmap = testmap.entrySet().stream()
    [javac]                                ^
    [javac]   symbol:   method entrySet()
    [javac]   location: variable streams of type Builder<String,Integer>
```

Can anyone point out what i'm doing wrong here? thanks much for all your help!

Comment: What do you think `testmap.build()` does? Might you need to assign the return value to something...?

Comment: In any case, mutating external variables from inside a `Stream` is pretty horrible. Your first case can be rewritten in a single line using `Collectors.toMap`. Your second case can be rewritten to use a custom `Collector`. I would strongly suggest you do some more reading about Java 8 before plunging into its depths.

Comment: Check the docs: https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMap.Builder.html and look at your own code. You don't actually have an Immutablemap anywhere but a builder to create one.

Comment: You are confused by your bad choice of names. You named your *ImmutableMap.Builder* `testmap` which lets you think `testmap` is a *Map* as it used to be in your first code snipped. **Always think careful when choosing identifier names!**.

Comment: By the way, there is no need for `Integer.toString(n)`; you can just use `"teststring-"+n` to get the desired result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to build map from builder. Update your code to:

```
ImmutableMap.Builder<String, Integer> testmapBuilder = ImmutableMap.builder();
IntStream.range(0, 100).forEach(n -> testmapBuilder.put("teststring-" + Integer.toString(n), 1));
ImmutableMap<String, Integer> testmap = testmapBuilder.build();
//your code...
```

Or update to this one

```
Map<String, String> testmap = IntStream.range(0, 100)
        .mapToObj(Integer::toString)
        .collect(collectingAndThen(toMap(n -> "teststring-" + n, o -> "1"), ImmutableMap::copyOf));
```